# Dull, but delightful

Tags: single-word-requests

This is gonna bother me because I know the word is escaping me, but I believe there's a word in english language that expresses something to the effect of "this is a [trying to convey dull/pedestrian but still quite intriguing/delightful] painting"

Comment: All that in one word? We can't even say "This is a painting" in one word!

Comment: Well, there are terms like "bucolic".

Comment: @HotLicks What if one doesn't find shepherds intriguing or delightful?

Comment: @Spagirl - Then use "EL&Uic" instead.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry, could you explain?

Comment: @Spagirl - So you don't find EL&U dull but delightful?

Comment: @HotLicks What UK idiom can substitute for 'pleading the 5th'?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly 'Anodyne'

The OED gives

> 1. Having the power of assuaging pain
> 2. *fig* Soothing to the mind or feelings.

and adds a Draft Addition dated March 2007 of

> Unlikely to provoke a strong response; innocuous, inoffensive; vapid, bland.

It seems to me that in common use and in the situation you suggest the meaning would be somewhat of a mash up of the figurative and draft additional definitions, bland and unexciting, but producing a beneficial mental effect.

Comment: assuaging pain / soothing sounds peaceful, but not sure it sounds delightful? It's the closest thing I've got though, so I'll take it!